# IE displaying fieldset legend incorrectly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The code I am using is appearing fine in FF but in IE, it resorts to the legend appearing almost in the fieldset with no space for the legend after the fieldset. I have included pic so you can see exact problem. I would be grateful if someone could show me where I am going wrong as I have spent 2 days trying to sort this. Thanks

Complete code layout: http://jsfiddle.net/XLPxx/

```
legend {
          background:#00C621; color:#fff; 
          font:17px/21px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
          padding:0 10px; margin:-26px 0 -5px -11px; 
          font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #fff; 
          border-color:#e5e5c3 #505014 #666661 #e5e5c3; cursor: pointer;
       }

fieldset.action {
          background:#9da2a6; 
          border-color:#e5e5e5 #797c80 #797c80 #e5e5e5; 
          margin-top:-20px;
       }

fieldset {
          background:#f2f2e6; 
          padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; 
          border:1px solid #fff; 
          border-color:#666661 #fff #666661 #fff; 
          margin-bottom:20px; width:450px;
        }
```

[image: As appears in IE8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a larger bottom margin to your `fieldset` and make it `display:block`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/XLPxx/7/

```
fieldset{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If html code in fiddle is marked as red, does that mean it is invalid? Thanks