# Bootstrap + Datatables + IE8 = Layout broken after inserting new row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am currently using Bootstrap 3.2 and Datatables 1.9.4 and unfortunately I have to make it work on IE8. The problem I am facing now is regarding the layout after I use datatable's fnAddData function to insert a new row.

The images below will exemplify it better: The first one is the layout right after the initial page load and the second one is the layout after I have added a new row to the table. As you can see the labels will overlap each other.

Image1 (before adding new row):

[image]

Image2 (after adding new row):

[image]

I am using "col-xs" class on my divs to make the container responsive to IE8, as follow:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset class="fieldset-tag">
        <div class="documentos" id="documentosDigitalizados">
            <label>Arquivos Digitalizados</label>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <table id="tabela-documentos">
                    <thead>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${emissaoCertificado.documentos}" var="documento" varStatus="i">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                ${documento.nomeDocumento}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" class="pkFile" value="${documento.pkFile}"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="verificarDocumentos_page.visualizar(this)">
                                    Visualizar
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <c:if test="${not empty pareceresAnteriores}">
            <legend>Verificações Anteriores</legend>
            <c:forEach items="${pareceresAnteriores}" var="parecerAnterior">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label>CPF do Agente </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="${parecerAnterior.cpfAgente}" disabled/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <label>Nome do Agente de Verificação</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${parecerAnterior.nomeAgente}" disabled/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label>Data</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss" value="${parecerAnterior.dataVerificacao}"/>" disabled/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Resultado Parecer</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${parecerAnterior.resultadoParecer.descricao}" disabled/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label>Observações</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" disabled>${parecerAnterior.observacao}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this layout problem?

Comment: could you provide more info? like a jsfiddle or css file? Seems like a float problem or fieldset and legend issue. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955749/ie-displaying-fieldset-legend-incorrectly

Comment: That Fiddle has nothing to do with your question..

Comment: You are right, I copied the wrong link... http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/576/

Comment: Sorry, I can't use jsFiddle in IE8 somehow.. Did you read the support section of Bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)? They have some issues with IE8 and you therefore need to take some special actions..

Comment: I did read it and I even added Respond.js and later when Respond.js didn't do anything I also tried to use css3-queries.js without any success as well